# Scrape number of rooms from Booking.com per room type

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape total number of rooms available according to room type at hotel's booking.com page but the problem is there are multiple select classes under that showing the number of rooms available at the moment and I want only the first select class from each room type. Here is the [link](https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/benica.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLUBiAEBmAEJuAEZyAEM2AEB6AEB-AEMiAIBqAIDuAKn9fqhBsACAdICJDk5NjkxYzcxLWM1ZGMtNDkyMC1hYTMzLWViODA3MmY2YzQ0NtgCBuACAQ&sid=17bbe3350ba8fd3998e8883df7bb3fdc&all_sr_blocks=7711208_105663500_0_1_0;checkin=2023-06-25;checkout=2023-06-30;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=7711208_105663500_0_1_0;hpos=1;matching_block_id=7711208_105663500_0_1_0;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=distance_from_search;sr_pri_blocks=7711208_105663500_0_1_0__42000;srepoch=1681836060;srpvid=473c754d9f8a0016;type=total;ucfs=1&#_) and here is the html source code:

```
<td class=" hprt-table-cell hprt-table-room-select ">
<div class="hprt-block">
<label for="hprt_nos_select_7711208_105663500_0_1_0"><span class="invisible_spoken">Select rooms</span></label>
<select
class="hprt-nos-select js-hprt-nos-select"
name="nr_rooms_7711208_105663500_0_1_0"
data-component="hotel/new-rooms-table/select-rooms"
data-room-id="7711208"
data-block-id="7711208_105663500_0_1_0"
data-is-fflex-selected="0"
data-testid="select-room-trigger"
id="hprt_nos_select_7711208_105663500_0_1_0"
aria-describedby="room_type_id_7711208 rate_price_id_7711208_105663500_0_1_0 rate_policies_id_7711208_105663500_0_1_0"
>
<option value="0">
0
</option>
<option value="1">
1
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 130,413)
</option>
<option value="2">
2
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 260,825)
</option>
<option value="3">
3
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 391,238)
</option>
<option value="4">
4
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 521,650)
</option>
<option value="5">
5
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 652,063)
</option>
<option value="6">
6
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 782,475)
</option>
<option value="7">
7
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 912,888)
</option>
<option value="8">
8
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 1,043,300)
</option>
<option value="9">
9
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 1,173,713)
</option>
<option value="10">
10
&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
(PKR 1,304,125)
</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I tried with the conventional parsing with BeautifulSoup but I am getting all the dropdown values:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.booking.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en,ru;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    # 'cookie': 'px_init=0; px_init=0; px_init=0; bkng_sso_session=e30; cors_js=1; OptanonConsent=implicitConsentCountry=nonGDPR&implicitConsentDate=1681743126414; _gid=GA1.2.1780790249.1681743127; BJS=-; _pxvid=6c31855f-dd2f-11ed-a917-4e68496f4d4b; _gcl_au=1.1.112323773.1681743130; _scid=229df030-2f68-4bd0-b156-7063f0145941; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU16Y3dNbVF6T0dNdE1tWTBOaTAwWTJSa0xUazVZakV0TXprek5XWm1ZV014WWprMw; _sctr=1%7C1681671600000; b=%7B%22countLang%22%3A4%7D; _gac_UA-116109-18=1.1681744759.CjwKCAjw3POhBhBQEiwAqTCuBoX_51XaQoBEeU_vfDuKDmXAjW8jLEbT8R7tq1wdrJL6KpXQsfNA4xoC4DEQAvD_BwE; _gcl_aw=GCL.1681744761.CjwKCAjw3POhBhBQEiwAqTCuBoX_51XaQoBEeU_vfDuKDmXAjW8jLEbT8R7tq1wdrJL6KpXQsfNA4xoC4DEQAvD_BwE; bkng_sso_ses=eyJib29raW5nX2dsb2JhbCI6W3siYSI6MSwiaCI6IjhzQXVjY1d5TERtc2Z5Qkx0MmRoRDVoSTk2Y1l6bUs3M0t2a09KSm5QckkifV19; bkng_sso_auth=CAIQARqEATEvPMc6AHwUEZvMw4J/8YklCkAg36aw5sLRh/H86hPARPQzeLVq/nBP5sTaXqr07pN2Ab1Mmi5R19Dv5D1jt0BN/JDzhkghfxoBBnu5V/XdrPyRvfXLgTGbi59fPQZ3vnaq6U5BXUQXBNsblbmPI1CPeF9Ru3TDPkOxycvKo4wnQ2Pe6g==; bkng_sso_auth_1681832614=CAIQARqEATEvPMc6AHwUEZvMw4J/8YklCkAg36aw5sLRh/H86hPARPQzeLVq/nBP5sTaXqr07pN2Ab1Mmi5R19Dv5D1jt0BN/JDzhkghfxoBBnu5V/XdrPyRvfXLgTGbi59fPQZ3vnaq6U5BXUQXBNsblbmPI1CPeF9Ru3TDPkOxycvKo4wnQ2Pe6g==; pxcts=ca12cab0-ddff-11ed-9fb5-7a696b416e65; _pxhd=m46ietwzHE0KPFcO%2FW8mTbqqF%2FcyHaDRq0EXc51i8O7gVmsl6vUyiTHTNhi7Us33okAykNXiLzHhvbNgAdwo6w%3D%3D%3AfmGY7mxZ1hNe3x07dauU-Ne2oBr8cGPiIFZUUXCkWC69duHocPv0KFdHymel2PP1Y2enqA8SeESGeV7eUDyj-JZYB6TGpE7AnKCRsXA216o%3D; bkng_prue=1; g_state={"i_p":1681919052255,"i_l":2}; 11_srd=%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A9%7D%5D%2C%22score%22%3A3%2C%22detected%22%3Afalse%7D; _scid_r=229df030-2f68-4bd0-b156-7063f0145941; _ga=GA1.1.713886904.1681743127; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9NEJfWVVGcWNmNWdUc2MtZl9BOVJfSjN4akVjX3pZZDImbj0tY2MxOFYyU1kwTWx1cUprYXdteEJ3Jm09OCZ0PUFBQUFBR1EteTdFJnJtPTgmcnQ9QUFBQUFHUS15N0Umc3A9NQ; _uetsid=6e37b7a0dd2f11edbcd7b5787f5f4105; _uetvid=bd8565c043f911edaa654360921b70d6; _ga_FPD6YLJCJ7=GS1.1.1681835994.3.1.1681836988.0.0.0; bkng=11UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9Yaa29%2F3xUOLbKE7bjkbYWzlZVOt73Ae4DLnjBW58p%2FU623mlquFQJ3RIz%2Bzw7Y4krv7gVyeCmeGPuNyEMFlfjZImfWmkko82%2B42f3Z0fCyOQmcn1FTTY911Kk8zkS6F%2FxxPaZExjSwq8wSEEO4Ncu81x7iQdDYB1cQT6iAlINUyTzQCPDKM8cpg%3D; _px3=ac834449c9b89fb1d80807b2633d16b99eaaab2c6660962d6ae3cc35b759432a:gkxp6/KH6Yemcpe9TK0KCaS+0Y6yjqjgApISMdA0eds9e+rmN8zCEQDOMlVczT3/Kat0mYjuTknyGrn7zW9qfw==:1000:3L//ZAiwJK2fw7/EGikj756ZBaHz5JX20iIwM/FTWwpPsGSmUUPF3EjBNlEGQYeMSidSYcdJkHggYtsv7klcuZmjJRjX9nq0QmPCcO2qmrWlscPd2hGRpAhGcpT4iA7IYRqu3DMJqcEI6nu4KLfX5AfhetkwR/cm4JJxFD90pPH1G2tl2hFrfpa9b060rzZKVR8/T1I4ozaFQcCackRF+g==; _pxde=50b64dac12bc11f5f5f6c4f2452f81227d13cc432a5c3dfa7219699e1232f77a:eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2ODE4MzcwNDE4NDYsImZfa2IiOjAsImlwY19pZCI6W119; lastSeen=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "YaBrowser";v="23"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.3.1.906 (beta) Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/benica.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLUBiAEBmAEJuAEZyAEM2AEB6AEB-AEMiAIBqAIDuAKn9fqhBsACAdICJDk5NjkxYzcxLWM1ZGMtNDkyMC1hYTMzLWViODA3MmY2YzQ0NtgCBuACAQ&sid=17bbe3350ba8fd3998e8883df7bb3fdc&all_sr_blocks=7711208_105663500_0_1_0;checkin=2023-06-25;checkout=2023-06-30;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=7711208_105663500_0_1_0;hpos=1;matching_block_id=7711208_105663500_0_1_0;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=distance_from_search;sr_pri_blocks=7711208_105663500_0_1_0__42000;srepoch=1681836060;srpvid=473c754d9f8a0016;type=total;ucfs=1&',
    headers=headers,
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
availabelRooms = []
empty_rooms = soup.select('select.hprt-nos-select.js-hprt-nos-select')
for e in empty_rooms:
    availabelRooms.append(len(e.select('option'))-1)
```

Above code outputs:

```
[10, 10, 10, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

And my expected output is:

```
[10, 4, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I can see, each dropdown box has it's own row.
Then each room type has mutliple rows
on the last row of a room type, the class for the div is different

Apologies for bad formatting, copy pasted from console

```html
<tr data-block-id="7711201_352735385_0_1_0" data-hotel-rounded-price="280" class="js-rt-block-row e2e-hprt-table-row hprt-table-last-row ">
```

vs for a non ending row:

```html
<tr data-block-id="7711201_105663500_0_1_0" data-hotel-rounded-price="250" class="js-rt-block-row e2e-hprt-table-row ">
```

As you can see the class is different.
If we assume that each row of a room type has the same number of rooms available, then you can simply do exactly what you're doing now but select the ending row of each room type:

```py
selector = "#hprt-table > tbody tr.e2e-hprt-table-row td div.hprt-block select"
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
availabelRooms = []
empty_rooms = soup.select(selector)
for e in empty_rooms:
    availabelRooms.append(len(e.select('option'))-1)
```

Comment: unfortunately same output `[10, 10, 10, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]` which I am getting with the previous selector.

Comment: Okay, well then I would test your code by reducing the selector down. Like start with `soup.select("#hprt-table")`, then add in > tbody,... and so on. This way you can see which part exactly it is that gets the wrong answer.

Comment: `soup.select("#hprt-table")` this also giving the same output.

Comment: soup.select returns a list of elements that matched the query. So `e.select('option'))-1)` in your last line, gets all the option tags in the whole #hprt-table. What you probably want is to first get all the last rows of each room type with soup.select (you will have to find the selector for these rows yourself). Then loop through those rows and then select the option tag in there and append that.

Comment: `e.select('option')` gets a list of all the option tags inside of e

Comment: After doing some attempts and with your excellent finding `last row` selector `"tr.js-rt-block-row.e2e-hprt-table-row.hprt-table-last-row"` this selector worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working. Would appreciate it if you could mark the answer as correct/accepted.